# Speed up a loop in r, using character strings simplification

Tags: r, for-loop, strsplit

I have a data frame `sp` which contains several species names but as they come from different databases, they are written in different ways.

For example, one specie can be called *Urtica dioica* and *Urtica dioica L.*.

To correct this, I use the following code which extracs only the two first words from a row:

```
paste(strsplit(sp[i,"sp"]," ")[[1]][1],strsplit(sp[i,"sp"]," ")[[1]][2],sep=" ")
```

For now, this code is integrated in a `for` loop, which works but takes ages to finish:

```
for (i in seq_along(sp$sp)) {
    sp[i,"sp2"] = paste(strsplit(sp[i,"sp"]," ")[[1]][1],
                        strsplit(sp[i,"sp"]," ")[[1]][2],
                        sep=" ")
}
```

If there a way to improve this basic code using vectors or an apply function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use vectorized regular expression functions:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("Urtica dioica", "Urtica dioica L.")
> str_extract(string = x,"\\w+ \\w+")
[1] "Urtica dioica" "Urtica dioica"
```

I happen to have found **stringr** convenient here, but with the right regex for your specific data you could do this just as well with base functions like `gsub`.

Comment: It works perfectly well ! Thank you. I do not know the regex to use with `gsub`. I tried this:`gsub(" .*$", "", x)` but it just keep the first word.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if there are more than 2 words in the string before doing each extraction:

```
if((sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", i), length) + 1) > 2){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it could be useful, sometimes I only have the family and not the specie. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function for that.

Also from `stringr`, the `word` function

```
> choices <- c("Urtica dioica", "Urtica dioica L..") 
> library(stringr)
> word(choices, 1:2)
# [1] "Urtica" "dioica"
> word(choices, rep(1:2, 2))
# [1] "Urtica" "dioica" "Urtica" "dioica"
```

These return individual strings. For two strings containing the first and last names,

```
> word(choices, 1, 2)
# [1] "Urtica dioica" "Urtica dioica"
```

The final line gets the first two words from each string in the vector `choices`

Comment: I did not know the `word` function, thanks ! After that, I need to use the `paste` function to merge the outputs and it works.

Comment: @user3443183 Actually, `word` does that too, see my edit

Comment: Indeed, a very useful function.